# Date(dateFormat.parse("string date").getTime()) Error

Tags: java, parsing, date-format

i have a string date `2020-01-14 00:00:00.0`
when i convert this string date using

`new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse("2020-01-14 00:00:00.0").getTime())`

this will result the date as `0019-07-13`

i am not getting how it is converting the string ...

pls help me

thanks

Comment: Show us how `dateFormat` has been defined.

Comment: what is `dateFormat`????

Comment: @Amanpreet: The attribute `dateFormat` called inside the `Date(...)` constructor is meant.

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat.parse()` is abstract, and `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is +- 120 lines long.  Presumably you're using SimpleDateFormat to do your parsing.  SimpleDateFormat is initialised using the format specified in your current [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) by default if you do not pass a specific format string to your call to SimpleDateFormat's constructor.

ensure that you initialise `dateFormat` as follows

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
```

and your issues should go away.